# Extract XML Request body variable into an nginx variable

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have an XML request body where I want to extract a value like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?><Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><Body><myvariable>123</myvariable></Body></Envelope>
```

I want to extract the value in the  tag, assign it to the nginx variable and then if the value is set, use it for rate limiting.

So far as far as my research goes, the only way to extract a regex based group from the $request_body variable is through the map like:

```
map $request_body $student_id {
    "~.*<myvariable>(.*)</myvariable>.*" $s;
    default 0;
}
```

My understanding is the $s variable will hold the capture group and then I can use it like:

```
if ($s = 123)
{
    rate_limit;
}
```

But the above is not working. Have someone done something like the above? Any pointers will be really appreciated.

Comment: You do NOT want to parse XML using regex.

Comment: I was only going to extract a single variable from the XML. So far I am able to achieve that.

Comment: ... as long as <myvariable> is a one liner. And I *think* `<` and `>` are metacharacters, so do they have to be escaped (to `\<` and `\>`) to match them literally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the map method, I will replace $s by $1 so it will assigned the extracted value to the student_id. Therefore you can use the student_id variable in your if statement. That's how I was able to extract the variable needed from the request body using your code.

Comment: Thank you very much. Yup. It worked!